# How to refresh display before returning to run loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to display a message in the foreground by calling `drawRect:` or by adding a view that appears in foreground. The message must be displayed after pressing a button. I have noticed that the message is displayed only if the function that is called when button is pressed had exited.

```
- (IBAction)testBtnPress:(id)sender {
    TestView *testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
    // processing to be done while the message is displayed
}
```

The `drawRect:` is called in the `TestView` class.
The rectangle with message is displayed after the processing to be done is finished, which is not convenient for my application.
Is there a way to display the message while the processing in running (the message will be "Processing... Please Wait").
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing must either be done in a background thread, or performed in the *next* iteration of the runloop, to give your UI changes time to be handled.

You can do the processing in the next iteration of the runloop with something like this:

```
TestView *testView = ... ;

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // processing to be done while the message is displayed
}];
```

Comment: Yes this is working, thank you. Is there another way to launch the message display in background and let the processing in the main thread

Comment: No; UI updates all occur on the main runloop. You cannot force them to occur at a time of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    TestView *testView = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it seems that the display is not refreshed until the function testBtnPress is exited, thanks anyway.